# Flutter and custom fonts

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

I have an app in flutter using different fonts from the same family, declared in pubspec.yaml like this:

```
fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 600
```

In my main.dart, to use Poppins as my default font for the whole app, I have declared:

```
theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
```

However, now comes my doubts:

1. by declaring `theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins')`, which one of the 3 fonts is used by default?
2. How do I make the difference in a `Text()` widget when I want to use Light/Medium/Bold?.
3. Do I really need to declare the `weight` for each font type Light/Medium/Bold in `pubspe.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextTheme to define how the fonts will be used.

```
final TextTheme textTheme = TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
      headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
    )

ThemeData(textTheme: textTheme)
```

Comment: BTW the default TextTheme is defined here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.htm.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still have the doubt regarding the font files....so, in my example, when (or where) do the files Poppins-Light and Poppins-Medium come into play?...in your example you use always "Poppins".

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara, right now, the link you posted gives 404 page not found, at least for me.

Comment: Correct link for TextTheme class which shows default values: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html

Comment: The `fontFamily` is `Poppins`. The `fontWeight` determines which asset from the family is used.